# Join two table to have each record in first have all rows in second

Tags: sql, database, join

I need to Join two tables where each row in the first table get every row in the second table.

Example

Table 1 :
InvoiceNo, Product code ,quantity

Table 2 :
Product code,Product name

In table 1 I, for each invoice record I have only some products, but in the output I have to get the all the products for each invoice keeping the quantity to 0 if that product is not included in the invoice.
How can I do this?

Comment: The best way to explain your requirements and get helpful answers for SQL questions is to give some example data, and what you'd expect as the result from your query. Also try to include any SQL you've already had a go at.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to guess at your table names but I think this would work as required:

```
SELECT  InvoiceNo, 
        ProductName, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice.ProductCode = Product.ProductCode THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Quantity
FROM    Invoice, Product
GROUP BY InvoiceNo, ProductName
```

**EDIT**

To get the data in the format you are after you need to use conditional `SUM`s as I don't think SQL-Server CE supports `PIVOT`. Something like this would work for you:

```
SELECT  InvoiceNum,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCode = 'P1' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) [Product 1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCode = 'P2' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) [Product 2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCode = 'P3' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) [Product 3]
FROM    Invoice
GROUP BY InvoiceNum
```

This only works though if you know all the products you have at the time of writing the code. if this is likely to change you can use dynamic SQL to create the above query but adding the products on the fly so when new products are added the query doesn't need to be changed. I haven't tested this on CE, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL, '') + ', SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCode = ''' + ProductCode + ''' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) ' + QUOTENAME(ProductName)
FROM    Product

SET @SQL = N'SELECT InvoiceNum' + @SQL + N'FROM Invoice GROUP BY InvoiceNum'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQL
```

I've put some examples using SQL-Server 2008R2 on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfbdf/2)

Comment: Thanks, Your query works fine. The output it gives is like the following
Invoice No Product Code Quantity
001          Product 1       1
001          Product 2       0

Is there a way I can get the output like this
Invoice Num Product1    Product2 Product 3 Discount
001         Quantity    Quantity Quantity    Total discount 
002         Quantity    Quantity Quantity    Totaldiscount

Comment: You need to PIVOT the output - is this SQL 2005 or greater or are we using MySql?

Comment: i'm using SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5

Comment: can you please provide me a sample query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CROSS JOIN - this produces all the rows from Product (table1) for each Invoice (table2). Then you can INNER JOIN to the invoice lines table to get the totals.

Is this what you need?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2f66/4

UPDATE:

(oops) When I said INNER join I mean LEFT, otherwise you eliminate the nulls :)

UPDATE:

Need to add grouping and add to the join to ensure that the lines product code was joined to the products table

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2f66/14

I get these results:

```
INVOICENO    PRODUCTCODE    QUANTITY   
INV0001      PROD01         1
INV0001      PROD02         2
INV0001      PROD03         0
INV0002      PROD01         0
INV0002      PROD02         0
INV0002      PROD03         0
INV0003      PROD01         0
INV0003      PROD02         0
INV0003      PROD03         0
```

Of course this is based on the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE InvoiceHeader
(
  InvoiceNo varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE InvoiceLines
(
  InvoiceNo varchar(10),
  ProductCode varchar(10),
  Quantity int
)

CREATE TABLE Products
(
  ProductCode varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO InvoiceHeader VALUES ('INV0002')
INSERT INTO InvoiceHeader VALUES ('INV0001')
INSERT INTO InvoiceHeader VALUES ('INV0003')

INSERT INTO InvoiceLines VALUES ('INV0001', 'PROD01', 1)
INSERT INTO InvoiceLines VALUES ('INV0001', 'PROD02', 2)

INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('PROD01')
INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('PROD02')
INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('PROD03')
```

Comment: can you please provide me a sample. I performed the cross join. but it gives the quantity wrong. how can i perform the inner join to the result.

Comment: the join gives correct number of records, but the quantity is wrong. it does not return null values

Comment: Are you sure? I get the right number for mine (assuming my understand is correct) I've updated the answer with the result that I get - can you update the question with the result you expect?